# How can I do pixel-wise multiple between CV_32FC1 and CV_32FC3 images in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am working on do a pixel-wise multiple between a 2-dimension imageA(CV_32FC1) with another 3-dimension imageB(CV_32FC3) with OpenCV, i.e. imageA pixel-wise multiply each R\G\B channel of imageB. This is same as broadcast imageA to 3-dimension along the 3-th direction, then pixel-wise with imageB.
Now, I do it by:

```
vector<Mat> temp{imageA, imageA, imageA};   // imageA is CV_32FC1
merge(temp, sampA);                         // sameA is CV_32FC3 now, and each channel is same as imageA
Out = imageB.mul(sampA);                    // imageB is CV_32FC3, and do pixel-wise with sameA
```

My Question is:
  Can I have another more effective way to do this purpose with OpenCV? Such like a function in OpenCV.

I know this is same as "Broadcast" in MXNet, i.e.  broadcast a 2-dimension image to 3-dimension image along the 3-th direction, and each channel of result is same the input 2-dimension image.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is my code to do multiply for CV_32FC3 and CV_32FC1

```
Mat matmul32F(Mat& bgr, Mat& mask)
{
    assert(bgr.type() == CV_32FC3 && mask.type() == CV_32FC1 && bgr.size() == mask.size());
    int H = bgr.rows;
    int W = bgr.cols;
    Mat dst(bgr.size(), bgr.type());

    if (bgr.isContinuous() && mask.isContinuous())
    {
        W *= H;
        H = 1;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < H; ++i)
    {
        float* pdst = ((float*)dst.data)+i*W*3;
        float* pbgr = ((float*)bgr.data)+i*W*3;
        float* pmask = ((float*)mask.data) + i*W;
        for ( int j = 0; j < W; ++j)
        {
            (*pdst++) = (*pbgr++) *(*pmask);
            (*pdst++) = (*pbgr++) *(*pmask);
            (*pdst++) = (*pbgr++) *(*pmask);
            pmask+=1;
        }
    }
    return dst;
}
```

---

Most efficient way to is iteration by yourself.

> I test three method for :
>
> A: use `merge` and `mul`
>
> B: use `cvtColor` and `mul`
>
> C: loop sing pointer and mutiply by hand.

As for time costing, in most case, `A ≈ B ≈ 2 x C` . A typical time costing is:

```
Test A: 3.23E-03 s
Test B: 3.26E-03 s
Test C: 1.85E-03 s
```

Comment: 哇咔咔，遇到同胞了。。This the fast way I found. I think, pointer operator and loop in only one function will save the time.

Comment: 恩，刚才还去你知乎逛了一下，顺便点了个关注。。。In my opinion, 'cvtColor' is the clearest, but I'm going to use the 'Pointer' one.

Comment: csu? 我知乎应该是弃耕了，水货太多。这样一直中英混合老外会不会一脸懵逼～ `Pointer` is faster, `cv::Mat::mul` is cleaner, while encapsulated pointer function is also clean. It depends what your real purpose. Choose what you like.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it is memory-ineffective, but theoretically correct. Calling A.convertTo(A, CV_32FC3); won't work unfortunately. The most efficient way is to call

> cv::cvtColor(A, A, CV_GRAY2BGR);

This will copy or reallocate memory, but in a slightly more efficient manner than the one you are currently applying (without creating extra headers for cv::Mats which act as views in the vector).

The reason why OpenCV doesn't support such multiplication is because of using Intel IPP library underneath and IPP also doesn't support such multiplication. This is what exactly is used in OpenCV for per element matrix multiplication:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-mul. Essentially the size of data in both A and B has to be the same for any of those functions to work and additionally, both A and B are assumed to be contiguous so in your case, reallocation or copying is neccessary.

Comment: Thankyou very much. This is exactly what I want to know. Thanks again.