# Subtract vignetting template from image in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have 750+ images, like this [`'test.png'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj3oP.jpg), that I need to subtract the vignetting in [`'vig-raw.png'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC7OD.jpg) from. I just started using `opencv-python`, so "I don't even know what I don't know".

Using GIMP, I desaturated `'vig-raw.png'` to create [`'vig-desat.png'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HKaR.png), which I then converted with Color to Alpha to create [`'vig-alpha.png'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dc11.png).

This is my attempt to subtract `'vig-alpha.png'` from `'test.png'`.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img1 = cv.imread('test.png',0)
img1 = cv.cvtColor(img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA) # add alpha channel to RGB image
print(img1[0][0]) # show alpha

img2 = cv.imread('vig-alpha.png',flags=cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # read RGBA image
print(img2[0][0]) #show alpha

img3 = cv.subtract(img1, img2)
img3 = cv.resize(img3, (500,250))
print(img3[0][0]) # show alpha

cv.imshow('result',img3)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, this is the [`'result'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohhLf.png). I need to produce a uniform shading throughout the image while leaving the original colors intact. I don't know the correct terminology for this sort of thing, and it's hard to search for a solution with what I do know. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As per `Rotem`'s answer, image file format matters. StackOverflow converted the PNG files I posted to JPEG, which did effect results while checking their answer. See the comment I left on `Rotem`'s answer below for more information.

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vignette template is not supposed to be subtracted, it supposed to be **scaled**.

The vignette correction process is known as [Flat-field correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-field_correction) applies:

`G = m / (F - D)`
`C = (R - D) * G`

When `D` is dark field or dark frame.

We don't have dark frame sample - we may assume that the dark frame is all zeros.
Assuming D=zeros, the correction formula is:
`G = m / F`
`C = R * G`

`m` = `mean(F)`, and `F` applies `vig-alpha`.
`R` is `test.png`.

---

For computing `G` (name it `inv_vig_norm`, we may use the following stages):

- Read `vig-alpha.png` as grayscale, and convert it to float in range [0, 1] (`vig_norm` applies `F`):

  ```
   vig = cv2.imread('vig-alpha.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
   vig_norm = vig.astype(np.float32) / 255
  ```
- Divide `m` by `F`:

  ```
   vig_mean_val = cv2.mean(vig_norm)[0]
   inv_vig_norm = vig_mean_val / vig_norm  # Compute G = m/F
  ```
- Compute `C = R * G` - scale `img1` by `inv_vig_norm`:

  ```
   inv_vig_norm = cv2.cvtColor(inv_vig_norm, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
   img2 = cv2.multiply(img1, inv_vig_norm, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)  # Compute: C = R * G
  ```

For removing noise and artifacts, we may apply Median Blur and Gaussian Blur over `vig` (it may be required because the site converted vig-alpha.png to JPEG format).

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('test.png')

vig = cv2.imread('vig-alpha.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read vignette template as grayscale

vig = cv2.medianBlur(vig, 15)  # Apply median filter for removing artifacts and extreem pixels.

vig_norm = vig.astype(np.float32) / 255  # Convert vig to float32 in range [0, 1]
vig_norm = cv2.GaussianBlur(vig_norm, (51, 51), 30)  # Blur the vignette template (because there are still artifacts, maybe because SO convered the image to JPEG).
#vig_max_val = vig_norm.max()  # For avoiding "false colors" we may use the maximum instead of the mean.
vig_mean_val = cv2.mean(vig_norm)[0]
# vig_max_val / vig_norm
inv_vig_norm = vig_mean_val / vig_norm  # Compute G = m/F

inv_vig_norm = cv2.cvtColor(inv_vig_norm, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # Convert inv_vig_norm to 3 channels before using cv2.multiply. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48338932/4926757

img2 = cv2.multiply(img1, inv_vig_norm, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)  # Compute: C = R * G

cv2.imshow('inv_vig_norm',  cv2.resize(inv_vig_norm / inv_vig_norm.max(), (500, 250)))  # Show inv_vig_norm for testing
cv2.imshow('img1', cv2.resize(img1, (500, 250)))
cv2.imshow('result', cv2.resize(img2, (500, 250)))
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Results:

`img1`:
[image]

`inv_vig_norm`:
[image]

`img2`:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate you, applaud you, and thank you! Wonderful Answer, Rotem! For future visitors using this answer: 1) Using ```'vig-alpha.png'``` (not converted to jpeg by SO) produced a black result image. To fix this, I just used ```'vig-raw.png'``` or ```'vig-desat.png'```. Median and Gaussian were not required, but didn't degrade the result either. 2) Your ```'vig-raw.png'``` must be a 1:1 ratio (size, and pattern) with the image you want to edit. ```'vig-raw.png'``` should **only** contain vignetting, and a background color. Anything else present in the image will degrade your result image!

Comment: Oh haha There you go! Sorry, still new here. Thanks again, Rotem!